# Running a Python Script in 32 Bit on 64 linux machine to connect to oracle DB with 32 bit client

Tags: python, oracle, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit, cx-oracle

I am trying to set up a cronjob that executes a python (3.6) script every day at a given time that connects to an oracle 12g database with a 32 bit client (utilizing the cx_Oracle and sqlalchemy libs). The code itself was developed on a win64 bit machine.

However, when trying to deploy the script onto an Ubuntu 16.04 server, I run into a dilemma when it comes to 32 vs 64 bit architectures.

- The server is based on a 64 bit architecture
- The oracle db is accessible via a 32 bit client
- my current python version on ubuntu is based on 64 bit and I spent about an hour of how to get a 32 bit version running on a 64 bit linux machine without much success.

The error I receive at this moment when trying to run the python script refers to the absence of an oracle client (DPI-1047). However, I already encountered a similar problem in windows when it was necessary to switch the python version to the 32 bit version and to install a 32 bit oracle client.

Is this also necessary in the ubuntu case or are there similar measurements needed to be taken? and if so, how do I get ubuntu to install and run python3.6 in 32 bit as well as the oracle client in 32 bit?

Comment: Keep the system python, and eventually install a new python version in its own virtenv.

Comment: so what about the oracle client then? is it no problem to stick to a 64 bit client on a 64 bit machine when actually a 32 bit version would be needed to access the database server?

Comment: 64bit processors (on x86 architecture) runs 32 and 64 bit programs in parallel. (for this reason you have 32bit and 64bit libraries installed, in parallel). Programs should not notice differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a bit confused about your question but this should give some clarification:

- A 32-bit client can connect to a 64-bit Oracle database server - and vice versa
- You can install and run 32-bit applications on a 64-bit machine - this is at least valid for Windows, I don't know how it works on Linux.
- Your application (the python in your case) **must** have the same "bitness" as installed Oracle Client.